# Express routes passing data to view

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have data that I am able to log to the console but can't figure out how to make it available to my view.

The following works to console.log req.user upon signing in to an admin page

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req.user);
  next();
});
```

The entire JSON object is passed into the console. I'd like to be able to pass it into my view but can't seem to make the following logic work. I'm either not passing it into the route correctly or not pulling it out into ejs correctly.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('index.ejs',{
          bootstrappedUser: req.user
        });
});
```

Comment: remove `.ejs` while rendering, what problem are you getting while accessing the data.

Comment: Your code looks okay here, you probably have an issue in your `index.ejs`, if you post it we could take a look and try and see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

What version of express are you using?, I dont see error in your code , but maybe in config files.Are you setting app.set('view engine','ejs')?,maybe your index.ejs file is not in the correct folder so you need to move it  to /views in the root folder of your application.